# :disable_with is not working with multiple buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

With a button `:disable_with` is working fine.

```
<%= link_to change_status_path(post), :class => "btn btn-large btn btn-danger", :disable_with => "<i class=\"icon-eye-close\"></i> #{t('.unpublish')}",  :confirm => t('.sure_unpublish'), :method => :put do %>
  <i class="icon-eye-close"></i>
  <%= t('.unpublish') %>
<% end %>
```

However if I add other button:

```
<%= link_to change_status_path(post), :class => "btn btn-large btn btn-danger", :disable_with => "<i class=\"icon-eye-close\"></i> #{t('.unpublish')}",  :confirm => t('.sure_unpublish'), :method => :put do %>
  <i class="icon-eye-close"></i>
  <%= t('.unpublish') %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to change_status_path(cv), :class => "btn btn-large btn btn-success", :disable_with => "<i class=\"icon-eye-open\"></i> #{t('.publish')}", :confirm => t('.sure_publish'), :method => :put do %>
  <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
  <%= t('.publish') %>
<% end %>
```

:disable_with is not working with multiple buttons.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What is rendered html?

Comment: I don't think `disable_with` works for `link`...